# Как сделать так, чтобы js скрипт работал с несколькими объектами?

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет помогите пожалуйста, у меня тут на сайте нужно выкладывать новости, и есть анонсы новостей, там просто заголовок и картинка.Недавно решить сделать так что-бы картинка в анонсе была как слайд-шоу. Я сделал, но работает только с одним анонсом новости, а с другим- нет.
Вот шаблон новости:
HTML Код:

```html
<div id="header"  class="div" 
style = "width:100%; 
height:100%; 
border: 2px solid #eec55f;">

 <div style = "position:relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;">

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg"  style="position:relative; 
opacity: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;">

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg" id="img_1"  style="position:absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;"  />

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/3c980dd2e9c909ada7377cc89885231b.jpg" id="img_2"  style="position:absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0); "  />

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/background-backgrounds-floral-flower-Favim.com-2429619.jpg" id="img_3"  style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); "  />

</div>

</div>
```

А вот код js 
JS Код:

```js
$(document).ready(function change_image(){

var image_count = 3;

 var interval = 5000; //пауза

 var time_out = 15; //скорость смены картинки

 var i = image_count;

 var timeout;

 var opacity = 100;

opacity--;

var j = i + 1;

var current_image = 'img_' + i;

if (i == image_count) j = 1;

var next_image = 'img_' + j;

document.getElementById(current_image).style.opacity=opacity/100;

 document.getElementById(current_image).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+opacity+')';

 document.getElementById(next_image).style.opacity= (100-opacity)/100;

 document.getElementById(next_image).style.filter=' alpha(opacity='+(100-opacity)+')';

 timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", time_out);

if (opacity==1) {

 opacity = 100;

 clearTimeout(timeout);

i++;

if (i>image_count) i=1;

timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", interval);

}   

change_image()

});
```

```js
var image_count = 3;
 var interval = 5000; //пауза
 var time_out = 15; //скорость смены картинки
 var i = image_count;
 var timeout;
 var opacity = 100;
 function change_image() {
 opacity--;
 var j = i + 1;
 var current_image = 'img_' + i;
 if (i == image_count) j = 1;
 var next_image = 'img_' + j;
 document.getElementById(current_image).style.opacity=opacity/100;
 document.getElementById(current_image).style.filter='alpha(opacity='+opacity+')';
 document.getElementById(next_image).style.opacity= (100-opacity)/100;
 document.getElementById(next_image).style.filter=' alpha(opacity='+(100-opacity)+')';
 timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", time_out);
if (opacity==1) {
 opacity = 100;
 clearTimeout(timeout);
i++;
if (i>image_count) i=1;
timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", interval);
 }
 }
change_image()
```

```html
<div id="header"  class="div" 
style = "width:100%; 
height:100%; 
border: 2px solid #eec55f;">

 <div style = "position:relative;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;">

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg"  style="position:relative; 
opacity: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;">

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg" id="img_1"  style="position:absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;"  />

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/3c980dd2e9c909ada7377cc89885231b.jpg" id="img_2"  style="position:absolute;
right: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
 opacity: 0;
 filter: alpha(opacity=0); "  />

<img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/background-backgrounds-floral-flower-Favim.com-2429619.jpg" id="img_3"  style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); "  />

</div>
</div>
```

Ребята помогите пожалуйста, всю голову сломал

Comment: Код не рабочий.

Comment: Он рабочий, картинки из интернета, но там скрипт не подключён, нужно подключить в html

Comment: Нерабочий код. Разметка не соответствует js коду.

Comment: У Вас к коде точно так `<script src=>"js/anons.js"</script>`?

Comment: Ой нет, у меня написано <script src="js/anons.js"></script>

Comment: Правьте вопрос: добавьте отступы, удалите лишние строки, воспользуйтесь `Ctrl + M` в редакторе... В-общем уделите время Вашему вопросу...

Comment: Готово, код выполняется

Comment: Прикрепил возможность запустить

Comment: Проблема в том, что вы привязываетесь к конкретным значениям идентификаторов картинок в js коде. Элементов с одинаковыми идентификаторами на одной странице быть не должно, это не валидная верстка. Браузер не выдает ошибку по этому поводу, однако метод .getElementById() предполагает что идентификатор используется правильно, он выбирает первый попавшийся элемент с выбранным id, игнорируя все последующие. Соответственно, стили применяются только к самой первой картинке из всех картинок с одинаковым id.

Comment: Как это изменить? Поменять на классы?

Comment: Да, можно поменять на классы и использовать выборку по классу .getElementsByClassName(). Однако, этот метод возвращает коллекцию элементов, а не один элемент, по этому нужно будет проходить по ней циклом и применять стили для каждого элемента в коллекции.

Answer (score 0):

Если опираться на существующий код, то можно сделать вот так:

```js
var image_count = 3;
var interval = 1000; //пауза
var time_out = 15; //скорость смены картинки
var i = image_count;
var timeout;
var opacity = 100;

function change_image() {
  opacity--;
  var j = i + 1;
  var current_image = document.getElementsByClassName('img_' + i);
  if (i == image_count) j = 1;
  var next_image = document.getElementsByClassName('img_' + j);
  
  restyleImg(current_image, next_image);

  timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", time_out);
  if (opacity == 1) {
    opacity = 100;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    i++;
    if (i > image_count) i = 1;
    timeout = setTimeout("change_image()", interval);
  }
}

function restyleImg(cur, next) {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(cur, function(el) {
    el.style.opacity = opacity / 100;
    el.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + opacity + ')';
  });
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(next, function(el) {
    el.style.opacity = (100 - opacity) / 100;
    el.style.filter = ' alpha(opacity=' + (100 - opacity) + ')';
  })
}

change_image()
```

```html
<div id="header" class="div" style="width:100%;height:100%;border: 2px solid #eec55f;">
  <div style="position:relative;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg" style="position:relative;opacity: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg" class="img_1" style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%;" />
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/3c980dd2e9c909ada7377cc89885231b.jpg" class="img_2" style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%;opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0); " />
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/background-backgrounds-floral-flower-Favim.com-2429619.jpg" class="img_3" style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%;opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0); " />
  </div>
  <div style="position:relative;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg" style="position:relative;opacity: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;">
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/img_resize.jpg" class="img_1" style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%;" />
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/3c980dd2e9c909ada7377cc89885231b.jpg" class="img_2" style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%;opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0); " />
    <img src="https://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/background-backgrounds-floral-flower-Favim.com-2429619.jpg" class="img_3" style="position:absolute;right: 0px;top: 0px;width: 100%;opacity: 0;filter: alpha(opacity=0); " />
  </div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!